# generating a unique string on pressing JButton and storing it into database table

Tags: java, mysql

I need to generate sequential number between 0-9 and want to display it in the JTextfield combined with the value from JCombobox(i.e.element of jcombobox+count)
as a string after pressing the JButton

When I select the first value from combobox and press the JButton the count should start from 0 and again when the second element from the combobox is selected the count should again start from 0 for second element and this should be the case for all other element of combobox.

For example-- when element 1 is selected and button is pressed the combined output should be  10,11,12,13... but,if in between this element 2 is selected
the output displayed in textfield should again start from 0 i.e.20,21,22...
and for element 3 the count should again start from 0 i.e. 30,31,32...

The combined output should be displayed in textfield

```
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.io.*;

    class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        JButton b1, b2;
        JComboBox jc;
        String name;
        JTextField t1;
        Connection con, conn;
        Statement st;
        PreparedStatement pst;
        ResultSet rs, rs1;

        Test() {
            setLayout(null);
            JLabel l1 = new JLabel("USER SELECTION :");
            l1.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 60);
            add(l1);
            jc = new JComboBox();
            jc.setBounds(230, 114, 120, 30);
            jc.addItem("SELECT");
            jc.addActionListener(this);
            add(jc);
            JButton b1 = new JButton("GENERATE PART NO. :");
            b1.setBounds(70, 340, 170, 30);
            b1.addActionListener(this);
            add(b1);
            t1 = new JTextField(10);
            t1.setBounds(270, 340, 200, 30);
            add(t1);
            JButton b2 = new JButton("BACK");
            b2.setBounds(190, 420, 120, 30);
            b2.addActionListener(this);
            add(b2);

            setSize(500, 500);
            setResizable(false);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/d03", "root", "");
                st = con.createStatement();
                String s = "select Userdata from user1";
                rs = st.executeQuery(s);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String name = rs.getString("Userdata");
                    jc.addItem(rs.getString("Userdata"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
            }

            finally {
                try {
                    st.close();
                    rs.close();
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR CLOSE");
                }
            }
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String str = ae.getActionCommand();
            if (str.equals("GENERATE PART NO. :")) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/d03", "root", "");
                    st = con.createStatement();

                    String s = "select value from user1 where Userdata='" + jc.getSelectedItem() + "'";

                    rs = st.executeQuery(s);
                    t1.getText();
                    if (rs.next()) {

                        String add1 = rs.getString("value");
                        t1.setEditable(false);

                        t1.setText("B" + add1);// B is the default value here which
                                                // is also concatenated
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR CLOSE");
                }
            }
            if (str.equals("BACK") == true) {
                new categ();
                setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Test td = new Test();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any question here. You should first take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And when you post code, please format and indent it correctly. Your indenting is horrible to read.

Comment: what logic should I use for  getting the desired output

Comment: Sorry, we won't do the homework for you. You should first try it by yourself. The good thing in programming is, that you can try something and see the result immediately. But you should start somewhere.

Comment: Sir,of course but i have been trying and I don't need the whole program ,just the right logic